# Configure Nginx to serve one endpoint only

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am using Flask.

I have my site configured in nginx at www.example.com/.

Now my requirement is to serve **one of the endpoint** in my app using different domain say `www.example2.com`.

so it can be accessed `www.example2.com/custom`

**Note that I want to use www.example2.com domain name only for this endpoint. Is this possible in Nginx?**

Here is my Nginx configuration for reference.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream flask {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/opt/app/mobifly.sock fail_timeout=0; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    server_name www.example.com www.example2.com;
    listen         80;

    client_max_body_size 2000M;
    proxy_read_timeout 6000;

    location / {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/project/path/to/project.sock;
    }

}
```

Currently I can access all the urls using both the domains but I want to configure as I specified above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another [server block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) exclusively for that `server_name` with a single `location` that matches `/custom` only.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com
    ...
    location / {
        ...
    }
}


server {
    server_name www.example2.com
    ...
    location /custom {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks is it good and efficient practice to create another virtual server.?

Comment: It is completely normal to do so